# Correct way to feed timestamps into RNN?

Tags: tensorflow

I built an RNN that predicts query execution time for an unseen query. I want to add a timestamp as a feature, as it probably helps to estimate whether the server is busy or not. How can I combine a date/time variable with my query vector and feed it into my RNN model?
Yes, I could calculate the time delta by hand and feed it as a float, but that feels like cheating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the model you are using, your goal is to translate date-time stamps into numerical features that can give some insight into when the server is busy.

If you have periodic server usage, then you might want to create a periodic numerical feature.  E.g. Hour # (0-23), or minutes, or maybe even week day # (0-6).  If you have a linear trend over time (think server usage is slowly going up on average), then you might want to also translate the date-time stamps into a correctly scaled feature of "time since ...".  E.g. number of days since first observation, or # of weeks, etc...

I hope that helps.

Comment: Correct - the goal is to know whether the server is busy. Am I reading your answer correctly, that there is no "standard" or "correct" way to convert a timestamp into a float/tf-variable to give my model as a feature?

Comment: It's problem specific.  If you have periodic usage, just using a float representation of the timestamp will not be enough.  The float representation will just continually increase as time goes on.  This is great for linear trends in time series, but not for periodic or seasonal data.  You can always create both types of features too.